Bearing capacity using the handheld cone penetrometer
I would just like to ask if I calculated the cone resistance (manometer reading/base area) for soil using a handheld cone penetrometer, is the cone resistance already the bearing capacity, or how can the bearing capacity be obtained? Attached is a picture of the equipment used. 
